# link_to create and destroy a resource from a different resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

The code below is working but I want to know if there is a better way to do it. Is this the correct RESTful way to do this? Any suggestions would be helpful. The basic requirement is that I need a way to create and destroy a membership from places/show.html.erb

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :source => :user

  def membership_for_user(user)
    self.memberships.select{|m| m.user_id == user.id}
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
end

class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @membership = Membership.new({:user_id => current_user.id, :place_id => params[:place_id]})
    unless @membership.save
      flash[:notice] = "Unable to become member."   
    end
    redirect_to place_path(params[:place_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    place_id = @membership.place_id
    @membership.destroy
    redirect_to place_path(place_id)
  end
end
```

places/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Join',   memberships_path(:place_id => @place.id), :method => :post %>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', @place.membership_for_user(current_user), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks odd - how can you both create and delete a membership on the same page?

Are you selecting one or the other of the link_to statements, or can a user have multiple memberships to the same place?

I'd consider:

- using a form_for(@membership) instead of the first link_to, with hidden_field :place_id
- loading the membership in the controller, which would simplify the 2nd link_to.

Answer (score 0):

@klochner is right; this is wrong. You need to create the membership beforehand and have a status attribute on the Membership, which you either update to "accepted" or just delete the membership, if you want to do it this way. Otherwise you need a form to create the membership first.